# site running ok on localhost but error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I dont understand what is going on here.

I built my website with ruby on rails on postgresql database.

And it runs perfectly find on the local server.

But I just deployed it to Heroku and I am receiving this error;

FYI, I created a procfile as suggested on Heroku's website.

> Application Error
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. Please try again in a few moments.
>
> If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

```
   2013-06-26T03:02:07.421697+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    2013-06-26T03:02:07.421506+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
    2013-06-26T03:02:07.421506+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    2013-06-26T03:02:07.421697+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    2013-06-26T03:02:07.421506+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    2013-06-26T03:02:07.421506+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
    2013-06-26T03:02:07.421697+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    2013-06-26T03:02:07.421697+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    2013-06-26T03:02:07.421697+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
    2013-06-26T03:02:07.421697+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `server'
    2013-06-26T03:02:07.439117+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2013-06-26T03:02:07.421506+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
    2013-06-26T03:02:07.421697+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `start'
    2013-06-26T03:02:08.750717+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2013-06-26T03:02:08.745131+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2013-06-26T03:12:15.338756+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 47851 -e $RACK_ENV`
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `start'
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836349+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836349+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836349+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836349+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836349+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836349+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `server'
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836349+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836349+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836349+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836349+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.836547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
    2013-06-26T03:12:21.865436+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2013-06-26T03:12:23.663577+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2013-06-26T03:12:23.677322+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2013-06-26T03:22:43.460462+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2013-06-26T03:22:48.976685+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 30463 -e $RACK_ENV`
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.590985+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.591157+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.590985+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.590985+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.590985+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.590985+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.591157+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.590985+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.591157+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `server'
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.591157+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.590985+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.590985+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.590985+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.590985+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.591157+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.591157+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `start'
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.591157+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    2013-06-26T03:22:54.621142+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2013-06-26T03:22:55.841091+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2013-06-26T03:22:55.859629+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2013-06-26T03:32:48.892316+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2013-06-26T03:32:52.032180+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 58591 -e $RACK_ENV`
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409527+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409527+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409527+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (Load
    Error)
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409527+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409527+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409527+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409527+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409527+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409527+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409527+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `server'
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.426193+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `start'
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    2013-06-26T03:32:54.409728+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
    2013-06-26T03:32:55.409933+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2013-06-26T03:32:55.424202+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2013-06-26T03:42:57.889181+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2013-06-26T03:43:02.239973+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 56589 -e $RACK_ENV`
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359693+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359693+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359693+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359693+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `const_get'
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359693+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `block in get'
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359693+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `each'
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359693+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `inject'
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359693+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler.rb:20:in `get'
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359889+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `server'
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359889+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:59:in `start'
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359889+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359889+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359889+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359889+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359889+00:00 app[web.1]:    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.378536+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2013-06-26T03:43:06.587742+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359693+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- thin (LoadError)
    2013-06-26T03:43:05.359693+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you have gem thin in your Gemfile?

The error is telling you that can't found **thin**

Answer (score 1):

in your Gemfile add  **ruby '1.9.3'**

Heroku is providing ruby 2.0 as default, so if you dont specify ruby version, then heroku will try to run ruby2.0 for your app, and it will cause error.

Comment: But I have `ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]` too.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `heroku logs -n 200` to print out more lines from the log - sometimes the actual errors are moved off screen due to truncated logs.